# I am trying to store my data using react-redux, but it doesnt. How can I solve this?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongoose, redux

I am working on a react project and when I try storing my data using postman, it works very well. But on the other hand, If i use react- redux, It doesn't get passed into the database. How can I resolve this? Here are some snippets of the code.

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const verifySchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    investment: {
      type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
      ref: 'Investment',
    },
    topup: {
      type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
      ref: 'TopUp',
    },
    verified: {
      type: Boolean,
      required: true,
    },
    verifiedBy: {
      type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
      ref: 'Auth',
    },
    dateVerified: {
      type: Date,
      default: Date.now(),
      required: true,
    },
    note: String,
    createdAt: { type: Date, default: Date.now() },
    paymentDates: [Date],
  },
  {
    toJSON: { virtuals: true },
    toObject: { virtuals: true },
  }
);

const Verify = mongoose.model('Verify', verifySchema);

module.exports = Verify;
```

This is the submit handler

```
const submitHandler = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (isConfirmed === true) {
      const paymentDates = [];
      for (let i = 1; i <= investment.investmentDuration; i += 1) {
        paymentDates.push(
          moment(dateConfirm).add(i, 'months').add(1, 'days').toISOString()
        );
      }
      const data = new FormData();
      data.append('verified', isConfirmed);
      data.append('investment', investment._id);
      data.append('dateVerify', dateConfirm);
      data.append('verifiedBy', userInfo.data.user._id);
      data.append('amount', investment.investmentAmount);
      data.append('duration', investment.investmentDuration);
      data.append('paymentDates', paymentDates);

      data.append('note', note);
      dispatch(verifyInvestment(data));
    }
  };
```

This is the action

```
export const verifyInvestment = (formData) => async (dispatch, getState) => {
  try {
    dispatch({ type: VERIFY_CREATE_REQUEST });

    const {
      userLogin: { userInfo },
    } = getState();



    for (var pair of formData.entries()) {
      console.log(pair[0] + ', ' + pair[1]);
    }


    const config = {
      headers: {
        // Authorization: `Bearer ${userInfo.token}`,
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
    };

    const { data } = await axios.post(`/api/v1/verify`, formData, config);

    dispatch({
      type: VERIFY_CREATE_SUCCESS,
      payload: data,
    });
  } catch (error) {
    dispatch({
      type: VERIFY_CREATE_FAIL,
      payload:
        error.response && error.response.data.message
          ? error.response.data.message
          : error.message,
    });
  }
};
```

From My console, I get this message printed

```
verified, true
verifyActions.js:16 investment, 5fcde10d1ec7da05d54942ed
verifyActions.js:16 dateVerify, 2020-12-31
verifyActions.js:16 verifiedBy, 5fcc8739b926611a541a5baf
verifyActions.js:16 amount, 400000
verifyActions.js:16 duration, 12
verifyActions.js:16 paymentDates, 2021-01-31T23:00:00.000Z,2021-02-28T23:00:00.000Z,2021-03-31T23:00:00.000Z,2021-04-30T23:00:00.000Z,2021-05-31T23:00:00.000Z,2021-06-30T23:00:00.000Z,2021-07-31T23:00:00.000Z,2021-08-31T23:00:00.000Z,2021-09-30T23:00:00.000Z,2021-10-31T23:00:00.000Z,2021-11-30T23:00:00.000Z,2021-12-31T23:00:00.000Z
verifyActions.js:16 note, Hello World
POST http://localhost:3000/api/v1/verify 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

I get this message from the state.
verify(pin):"Verify validation failed: verified: Path `verified` is required."

Please I really do need help in resolving this.
If i try posting it using postman, It gets stored on the database but for this instance, it doesn't. I dont know if I have to empty some states before posting the data.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try setting Content-Type header to "multipart/form-data". After all you are not posting JSON, you are posting FormData object.

If you are sending it from postman as json object, then you should do it in code too. But if you send it from postman as FormData then you should change the header.

Comment: Same thing. Even if I try to send as json object, it returns same.

Comment: Can you edit your question and add API endpoint function as well? When you get error 500 it means you have Internal Server Error. I'm not sure that I can diagnose the problem just from frontend side.